# Angular type error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular6

I'm very new to angular and am trying to build an electron app leveraging angular 6.

What I'm trying to do is:
1. SupportInformationClass has a few definitions 
2. On init of the componenet, populate the definitions from the electron-settings

**supportInformation.ts:**

```
export class SupportInformation  {

    appsSet1: string[];
    //appsSet2: string[];
    //appsSet3: string[];
    //appsSet4: string[];
}
```

**configuration.componenet.ts:**

```
import { SupportInformation } from './supportInformation';
...
...
export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {

    supportInformation: SupportInformation;


    constructor(private childProcessService: ChildProcessService, private electronService: ElectronService) {
        console.log("inside constructor...")
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("on ngInit...");
        this.getSupportedApps();
    }

    getSupportedApps() {
        if(this.childProcessService.isElectronApp){

            // this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = ["wow"] // this works

            console.log(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1')) // this also works
            this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1'); // this gives an error
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with an error on this particular line even though this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1') returns an array of string elements.

```
this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1');
```

Error:

```
Type 'JsonValue' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

My settings file is like below:

```
{
...
    "APPS_1": ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
    "APPS_2": ["mno", "pqr"],
...
}
```

console.log(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1')) gives:

[image]

I'm unable to understand why. Could someone give me some pointers regarding the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the data for settings & how it looks

Comment: Ouput of `console.log(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1'))` ?

Comment: normally settings are key value pairs with a literal on the right hand side. If you've put json in there, perhaps it needs to be destringified. You could also just parse out the seperators (string replace [ with null string for example) and then string split on ','.

Comment: of course by de-stringify I mean JSON.parse() . So you say var jsonversion  = JSON.parse(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1'));

Comment: @Abdul / David- updated the question.

Comment: @JeffDavies - I tried ```this.supportInformation.meteorApps = JSON.stringify(this.electronService.settings.get('METEOR_APPS'))``` but I run into a similar error: ```Argument of type 'JsonValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.```
Also, if you notice the console statement, it is already in a js array format.

Comment: at what point yuo get error?   what is the return type of this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1');

Comment: @codeSetter ```this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1');``` the error is at this line.

Comment: not sure but try     this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = <[]>this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1');

Comment: JSON.stringify is the opposite of JSON.parse. You don't want to this.supportInformation.meteorApps = JSON.stringify  but this.supportInformation.meteorApps = JSON.parse please re-read what I posted.  You want to convert from string to json. Stringify converts json to string. Parse converts string to json.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse your response and then assign.
try this i hope it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrejs1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You need to JSON.parse to convert your string to a json object:

```
import { SupportInformation } from './supportInformation';
...
...
export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {

    supportInformation: SupportInformation;


    constructor(private childProcessService: ChildProcessService, private electronService: ElectronService) {
        console.log("inside constructor...")
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("on ngInit...");
        this.getSupportedApps();
    }

    getSupportedApps() {
        if(this.childProcessService.isElectronApp){

            // this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = ["wow"] // this works

            console.log(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1')) // this also works
            this.supportInformation.appsSet1 = JSON.parse(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1')); // this gives an error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff - I undestand the ```JSON.parse() , JSON.stringify()``` point. When I do a ```console.log(this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1'))```, it is already in a JS array format - doing a ```JSON.parse()``` - going by the screenshot in the OP on that lead to further errors. Either way, I happened to get it working and have posed an ansewer to my own question. Just that at the moment I'm trying to figure out why it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, picking up on the clues left by @codeSetter -`<[string]>this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1')` and with some help from the official angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) the following seems to work fine. The only problem now being, [I don't know WHY it works](http://m.memegen.com/ou7qcz.jpg).

Below is the implementation:

**supportInformation.ts:**

```
export class SupportInformation  {
    appsSet1: string[];
}
```

**configuration.componenet.ts:**

```
import { SupportInformation } from './supportInformation';
...
...

export class ConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {

  supportInformation: SupportInformation = {
        appSet1: []
  };
constructor(private childProcessService: ChildProcessService, private electronService: ElectronService) {
        console.log("inside constructor...")
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("on ngInit...");
        this.getSupportedApps();
    }

    getSupportedApps() {
        if (this.childProcessService.isElectronApp) {
            this.supportInformation.appSet1 = <[string]>this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1');
        }
        console.log("this prints what I need: ", this.supportInformation);

    }

}
```

Comment: <[string]>this.electronService.settings.get('APPS_1'); by doing this you were typecasting that JSON to string array.